# XML-RPC Javascript Unsupported method ('OPTIONS')

Tags: javascript, python, http, xml-rpc

We've got an XML-RPC server (implemented in python), and I'm trying to write a simple javascript app to send calls to it. Whatever library I make I seem to always get the error:

```
Unsupported method ('OPTIONS')
```

It's fair to say I don't understand the underlying protocols for XML-RPC and HTTP as well as I should. But what I do know is that this works in python:

```
client = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('http://localhost:2002')
client.T.run_process()
```

But the following javascript doesn't:

```
var client = new xmlrpc_client("", "localhost", 2002, "http")
var msg = new xmlrpcmsg("T.run_process()", {})
lert(client.send(msg));
```

I'm using this [javascript library](http://phpxmlrpc.sourceforge.net/jsxmlrpc/). But it seems I get the same error no matter what library I use, so I guess our server isn't conforming to some protocol that python doesn't mind about, is this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#introduction) in action.

Answer (score 2):

Using the standard SimpleXMLRPCServer from python, adding the following to the RequestHandler methods seemed to work for me:

```
class RequestHandler(SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler):
    rpc_paths = ('/RPC2',)

    def do_OPTIONS(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()

    # Add these headers to all responses
    def end_headers(self):
        self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 
                         "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept")
        self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler.end_headers(self)
```

Answer (score 0):

Julian is probably right. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144899/help-yui-async-get-request-using-https-defaulting-to-options-request-method/3148803#3148803) for details and some more links.

Answer (score 0):

I was fighting against something similar recently.

The problem is that python's XMLRPC server does not include CORS headers (nor respond HTTP OPTIONS request) in the XML-RPC request.

I'm using Twisted to serve the XMLRPC Resource, and solved that adding the OPTIONS response and the headers to the XMLRPC request.

My code looks something like:

```
from twisted.web.xmlrpc import withRequest

class MyResourceEndpoint(xmlrpc.XMLRPC):
    def render_OPTIONS(self, request):    
        request.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        request.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS')        
        request.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept')
        return ""

    @withRequest
    def xmlrpc_my_method(self, request, my_params):
        request.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        request.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS')        
        request.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept')
        return "Whatever your method do"

root = resource.Resource()
root.putChild('', MyResourceEndpoint())
reactor.listenTCP(9090, server.Site(root))

reactor.run()
```